# Is Comment.Id immutable in Word JavaScript API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The Word.Comment class has an Id property. Does anyone know for certain if this is immutable, or can it change between edits or sessions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.comment?view=word-js-1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in most cases a comment Id is persisted once the comment has been created. However, this depends on how the comment was created.

When you create a comment in the current version of Word, word creates a comment Id which it saves in an XML property called `durableId` when it saves the file. (I think it can save that in more than one place as there is a CommentIds part and a CommentsExtensible part in the .docx (or whatever)

e.g. the element would look something like this:

```
<w16cex:durableId="6AF7AF0C"
```

If the comment has had that `durableId` assigned, then JavaScript will see the same Id all the time, even when you close and re-open the document and Word itself.

However, if the document was created in an older version of Word (e.g. I used Word 2013 here to to this) then Word does not create a durableId. In that case, if you open the document in a modern version of Word, Word will create a `durableId` for each comment. That Id will last as long as the document is open, and if you or your JavaScript saves the document, the Id will be stored in a durableId element and will be the same the next time it is opened. If the document is not saved, then the same comment will have a different Id the next time you open it.

However, I do not know for sure what happens if you, for example, have track changes enabled, delete comments, then restore them in the review process.

Also, presumably if you saved your document in some old formats such as .doc,  perhaps .rtf, the `durableId` would probably be discarded and lost.

I used this simple snippet of code in ScriptLab to inspect comment IDs:

```
const comment = context.document
   .getSelection()
   .getComments()
   .getFirst();
await context.sync();
console.log(parseInt(comment.id,10).toString(16));
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems pretty robust. I did a bit of experimentation building on what you said here. Comments are not treated as tracked changes, so that eliminates some of the potential scenarios. If you use Combine then the ids are not lost if you merge the comments into the existing document, though they are lost if you put the result into a new document.

Comment: @PeterDongan - sounds as if you have already gone well beyond what I was able to discover. IMO if you end up being able to create a better summary/overview, please  post as a better answer to your question!